# What about Java applets? What are disadvantages?

Tags: java, applet, ria, java-web-start

Why are Java applets so unpopular nowadays?

Isn't it possible to create any rich internet application with Java applets? Why has Java Web Start emerged? Why do applets need to run in a separate window but not in browser window?

I need SHORT killing answer, without long boring comparison of several technologies.

**UPDATE**

Not surprised question is closed, since this is taboo. I still wish to know the answer.

Comment: I'm not putting this as an answer, BUT: security issues. Think about the latest holes, Apple removed Java from their OS X and disabled applets. People are used to HTML5-stuff that won't require much effort on the client side.

Comment: *"I need SHORT killing answer,"*  I'm not sure about the 'killing' but there is no good answer that is 'short'.  I can tell you that as the top scoring provider of answers to both applet and Java Web Start questions, I far prefer the simplicity of developing JWS apps.

Comment: @Blacklight neither technology is absolutely secure. Apple removed Java because of Apple's unfair business. This is not what I interested in.

Comment: @SuzanCioc Granted, but I wasn't only referring to the security issues itself, but the situation users are in. Wether you like Apple's move or not (depends solely on the viewpoint), applets require a plugin. Why putting users through this effort, if modern browsers are capable of doing most things with HTML5 and JavaScript?

Comment: @Andrew, if you can't post the short answer, then it probably does not exist. Can you confirm this? Can you confirm that technologically applets are not worse than JWS? Or what do you mean by simplicity? Can JSW app work in browser window?

Comment: @Blacklight HTML5 option has problems with backward compatibility.

Comment: It is the 'in browser' window that causes all the problems.  1) Focus problems between HTML elements and the applet or applets.  Sun never bothered to try and define what should happen, which resulted in either the applet or HTML getting focus, and that was it (as far as the keyboard went). 2) Typically there is at least one version of one browser that cannot load the simplest of applets correctly.  My 'favorite' of all these type of bugs was a FF version that reloaded applets if the user scrolled 'up'.  I could go on, and on, and on.. 3) Then there is the matter of the PLAF of the applet..

Comment: @SuzanCioc Backwards compatibility is a canard; old browsers are *rapidly* dying out. Java has similar issues with forward compatibility anyway. You can argue until you're blue in the face, but for any number of reasons, some technical, some not, applets are essentially dead, and have been for years.

Comment: It has nothing to do with being "taboo", rather off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 3):

There's almost never a reason to use an applet unless you have a strong need to re-use a bunch of already-written code. Modern browsers are completely capable of doing most of what applets were once used for. (Ignoring potential security issues.)

Before browsers could do much of anything useful, there was a *need* to turn to a more-capable platform. This is no longer the case, and as such, applets rarely have a place. Other client-based plugin technologies are suffering similar fates (think Flash).

Comment: Java applet is written in well-defined language, while AJAX RIAs are written in strange mixture of many languages which causes more efforts to write (ceteris paribus). I don't understand why if both A and B can the same, but B is harder, B becomes preferable.

Comment: @SuzanCioc Because (B) isn't harder, it's easier. JavaScript is *also* a well-define language, and delta a few major language warts, is very capable and expressive. It is automatically cross-browser, and the current crop of JS libraries eliminate all but the most edge-case cross-browser compatibility issues--and this will only get better as HTML5 toolkits mature. Java, OTOH, requires (relatively) large downloads, is generally less-attractive (unless you further increase download size), etc. JavaFX was invented for a reason, but again--modern browsers simply don't need an external environment.

Answer (score 0):

Java isn't a web language. Why rely on a browser plugin when you can just target the browser itself? HTML5 and Javascript are extremely powerful in modern browers, which does away with the need for cumbersome plugins.

Comment: applets aren't browser plugins. It is actually the code which browser runs as bytecode using jvm and java is in fact much more faster than javascript itself. but as @Dave Newton said above.. "Before browsers could do much of anything useful, there was a need to turn to a more-capable platform. This is no longer the case, and as such, applets rarely have a place." with which i agree

Comment: Chrome, Firefox, IE, etc. dont support Java out of the box. You need to run a plugin to see Java applets.

Comment: The question is about times before `HTML5`. Rely on plugin is required because browser do not support java natively which is due to unfair business competition. I am interested in whether technical reasons exist.

Comment: @SuzanCioc Your question says nothing about pre-HTML5. If you're asking why Java applets essentially died years ago, however, the answers will remain essentially the same: better options existed. Every major browser supported applets, and for a minority of web applications, applets made sense. But the bulk of web apps, especially years ago, didn't need what applets brought to the table, and they died of natural causes.